# When marker is moved it doesn't get back to the user location after floating button is clicked

Tags: flutter, dart, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I am trying to build google map with a floating button that when clicked it get the user location with a marker and the camera is moved towards is. I also made the marker draggable but when the marker is dragged and the floating button is clicked, the camera moves to the user position but the marker does not

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';
class Maps extends StatefulWidget {
  const Maps({super.key});
  @override
  State<Maps> createState() => _MapsState();
}
class _MapsState extends State<Maps> {
  late GoogleMapController mapController;
  static const CameraPosition initialCameraPosition = CameraPosition(target: LatLng(31.20121, 29.92914), zoom: 12);
  Set<Marker> marker = {};
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  BitmapDescriptor markerIcon = BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarker;
  void addCustomIcon(){
  }
  void _openDrawer() {
    _scaffoldKey.currentState?.openDrawer();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      drawer: Drawer(),
      body: GoogleMap(
        onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
        initialCameraPosition: initialCameraPosition,
        markers: marker,
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton.extended(
        onPressed: () async {
          Position position = await _determinePosition();
          mapController.animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(CameraPosition(target: LatLng(position.latitude, position.longitude), zoom: 20)));
          marker.clear();
          setState(() {marker.add(Marker(draggable: true, markerId: const MarkerId('currentLocation'),position: LatLng(position.latitude, position.longitude),));});
        },
        label: Text(""),
        icon: const Icon(Icons.my_location),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _onMapCreated(GoogleMapController controller) {
    mapController = controller;
  }
  Future<Position> _determinePosition() async {
    bool serviceEnabled;
    LocationPermission permission;
    serviceEnabled = await Geolocator.isLocationServiceEnabled();
    if (!serviceEnabled) {
      return Future.error('Location services are disabled');
    }
    permission = await Geolocator.checkPermission();
    if (permission == LocationPermission.denied) {
      permission = await Geolocator.requestPermission();
      if (permission == LocationPermission.denied) {
        return Future.error("Location permission denied");
      }
    }
    if (permission == LocationPermission.deniedForever) {
      return Future.error('Location permissions are permanently denied');
    }
    Position position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition();
    return position;
  }
}
```

this is my class

Comment: Where does the marker go after clicking the floating button?